# How to get into pts/0 again after accident disconnect

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I remote into my Pi from outside using SSH. My home router was disconnecting the SSH connection, ( after about 30 seconds if not active). So, after I SSH into my Pi again it creates a new process as pts/1, pts/2 ... But I need access into the last console again (pts/0), Can someone suggest how to get into the pts/0 process?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It is impossible to connect to a abandoned ssh session. For future, you can use the `GNU screen` utility and when you login back, you can get your session back by typing `screen -r` .